# Only print an item once from Model in the View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Model that produces an IENumerable, so I already have a foreach loop to iterate and organize each of my model's contents. However, I have one piece of the model that I only want to print once. Here is what I have now:

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Site == "Source Search")
    {
        <a href="@item.URL" target="_blank">More Results</a>
    }
}
```

The problem is that this causes it to print the link 50 times (how many items I have in each Model), but I only want it once.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a flag.

```
bool found = false;

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Site == "Source Search" && !found)
    {
        found = true;

        <a href="@item.URL" target="_blank">More Results</a>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to simply add a `break` to exit the loop after it's first rendered:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (item.Site == "Source Search")
    {
        <a href="@item.URL" target="_blank">More Results</a>
        break;
    }
}
```